# How can I start a new activity in a ScreenSlidePagerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I Have a FragmentActivity where I have a ScreenSlidePagerAdapter that shows many fragments with the getItem() method, for swipe between fragments. I want that once the user finalized swipping the fragments (from 0 to 15 for example) there's going to open a new activity showing the results of what the user had done navigating the fragments (it's a course).

What I need is an intent for open a New Activity after the fragments.

This is my code:

```
    package activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.flixarts.ar.*.R;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment1;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment10;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment11;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment12;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment13;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment14;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment15;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment2;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment3;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment4;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment5;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment6;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment7;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment8;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.fragment9;
import com.flixarts.ar.*.menuscreen;

public class saludos extends FragmentActivity implements      fragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener, fragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener, fragment3.OnFragmentInteractionListener, fragment4.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

private TextView espacioFrases;
private TextView espacioFrasesTraducidas;
private Button next;
private Button buttonHome;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 15;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludos);
 mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);



}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() -1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0: return new fragment1();
            case 1: return new fragment2();
            case 2: return new fragment3();
            case 3: return new fragment4();
            case 4: return new fragment5();
            case 5: return new fragment6();
            case 6: return new fragment7();
            case 7: return new fragment8();
            case 8: return new fragment9();
            case 9: return new fragment10();
            case 10: return new fragment11();
            case 11: return new fragment12();
            case 12: return new fragment13();
            case 13: return new fragment14();
            case 14: return new fragment15();
            //Here I want to start new activity
            default: return new fragment1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

I've trying create an intent with getActivity() but this method wasn't loaded in Android Studio (maybe this is old).

Comment: Just use `startActivity(FragmentActivity.this,ClassName.class )`.

Answer (score 2):

You should write the startactivity code inside last showing fragment of adapter. (If you are using instances of same fragment, then you have to pass the position from adapter to fragment while creating it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is getContext() the same as getApplicationContext or getBaseContext()? because the editor has a message getContext cannot resolve method

Comment: It is simply getApplicationContext(). I copied it from a fragment, that's why using getContext(). If getApplicationContext is there, you can use.

Comment: Pramod Moolekandathil how are you... I've writted that intent in a method (public void openActivity() {Intent intent...startActivity) inside the fragment but I don't know how to call the method now...

Comment: @MauroStancato I hope you have an onclick or such event for making sure the user finished with the contents in the page (May be a finish button / skip icon). When clicking that button, check whether you are in last fragment using the parameter you passed to fragment and call the method if condition satisfies. (If you dont have any click or other actions but to do it automatically, use a postDelayed method of handler to achieve this)

Comment: I have working now, I had to write the Intent in the onCreate method of the fragment, thanks!